# WIX toolset execute file after installation

Tags: python, wix, custom-action

I am trying to put together a installation file for my python application. I have created the installation file and installed and it is working great. Now I want to add a custom action onto the end of the installation that will execute a file that will setup my database before the user first starts the program. Here is my code so far:

Test.wxs

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>

  <Product Name='First App' Id='625F5886-BA33-4332-8831-18960B95D1EF' UpgradeCode='D94D7010-273B-46CA-848B-607C9DF55B3F'
Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version='1.0.0' Manufacturer='Fake Inc'>

    <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="Fake App will do everything"
  Comments='Fake App is a registered trademark of Acme Ltd.' Manufacturer='Fake Inc'
  InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Icon Id="test.ico" SourceFile="C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\test.ico"/>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

        <Directory Id="PersonalFolder"  Name="PersonalFolder">
            <Directory Id="Fake"  Name="Fake">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Fake App">
                    <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='D6388D5A-845A-4EE6-84D5-75E30E201E5F'>
            <File Id='UIStart.bat' Name='UIStart.bat'  DiskId='1' Source="C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\UIStart.bat" Vital='yes'/>
            <File Id='main.py' Name='main.py'  DiskId='1' Source="C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\main.py" Vital='yes'/>
            <File Id='UIStart.exe' Name='UIStart.exe'  DiskId='1' Source="C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\UIStart.exe" Vital='yes'/>
            <RemoveFolder Id="Fake Inc" On="uninstall"/>
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
                <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="Fake">
                    <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutStartMenu" Guid="{b449021b-a21f-4700-9c44-759e3fb77c47}">
                        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
                            Name="Fake App"
                            Description="Fake App shortcut"
                            Target="[#UIStart.bat]"
                            WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION"
                            Icon ="test.ico"/>

                        <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"
                              Name="Uninstall Fake App"
                              Target="[System32Folder]msiexec.exe"
                              Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"
                              Description="Uninstalls My Application" />

                        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuFolder" On="uninstall"/>
                        <RegistryValue
                            Root="HKCU"
                            Key="Software/Fake"
                            Name="installed"
                            Type="integer"
                            Value="1"
                            KeyPath="yes"/>
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
        </Directory>


        <Directory Id="DesktopFolder"  Name="Desktop">
            <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="{A072CB7F-5598-4d1c-85E3-C119659B1B19}">
                <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut"
                    Name="TFake App"
                    Description="Comment field in your shortcut"
                    Target="[#UIStart.bat]"
                    WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION"
                    Icon ="test.ico"/>
                <RemoveFolder Id="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>
                <RegistryValue
                    Root="HKCU"
                    Key="Software/Fake"
                    Name="installed"
                    Type="integer"
                    Value="1"
                    KeyPath="yes"/>
                </Component>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Property Id="JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION">
      <RegistrySearch Id="JRE_KEY" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" Name="CurrentVersion" Type="raw" Win64="no" />
    </Property>
    <Condition Message="Java not installed  Please install JRE 1.6 or later."><![CDATA[(Installed OR JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION) AND JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION >= "1.6"]]></Condition> 


    <Feature Id='Complete' Level='1' ConfigurableDirectory ='INSTALLLOCATION'>
        <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />
        <ComponentRef Id='ApplicationShortcutStartMenu' />
        <ComponentRef Id='ApplicationShortcutDesktop' />

    </Feature >

    <Property Id="QtExecCmdLine" Value="UIStart.exe"/>
    <CustomAction Id="QtExecCmdLine" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="QtExecCmdLine" After="InstallFinalize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>


   </Product>


</Wix>
```

When this is compiled and run the program installs but I get the following error:

the installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2762

How do I execute UIStart.exe at the end of the installation automatically?

Thank you for any and all help

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't miss anything: You defined your CustomAction but you didn't schedule it. So it is contained within the file but as it is in no schedule, it won't be invoked at all.
So the entry in the `InstallExecuteSequence` is missing. Also note that the `Value` of the property `QtExecCmdLine` contains the command line that should be invoked, so in your case `UIStart.exe` has to be in the path.
Also note that the `Id`-attribute of the CustomAction has to match the `Id` of the related property, i.e.

```
<Property Id="QtExecCmdLine" Value="UIStart.exe"/>
<CustomAction Id="QtExecCmdLine" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />
```

Refer to the [official documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html) or the [WiX tutorial @Tramontana](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/standard-libraries/silence-please) where you can find examples on how to implement it.

Comment: I just added the InstallExecuteSequence, and matched up the IDs, but now I get the following error: the installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2762

Comment: Could it be that you scheduled your custom action before `InstallInitialize` or after `InstallFinalize`? Deferred custom actions have to be within that range. You can find a very understandable and good description of the single phases [at this InstallSite-article](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/). Try to schedule it `Before="InstallFinalize"` in the `InstallExecuteSequence`, then you should get rid of this error.

Comment: When I add Before="InstallFinalize" in the InstallExecuteSequence I don't get an error but the program does not install.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer: the `Value`-attribute of the property carries the command line that will be executed. Now without any path given as in your example code the `UIStart.exe` has to be in the path (e.g. try putting this exe in the WindowsFolder\system32). For detailed information about what happens try to create a logfile during installation, e.g. invoking the following on the command line: `msiexec /i <myMSI.msi> /l myMSI.log` (replace `myMSI.msi` with your filename, of course). Then you will have a logfile `myMSI.log` in the same path which you can then scan for your custom action.